# Manage secret key in django settings

Tags: python, django

Following a deprecated post and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31883650/5530234) I have set up a separate file for storing `SECRET_KEY` and importing it into the main `settings.py` file. However, I am getting the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named 'settings_secret'
```

**settings_secret.py**

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '..key'
```

**settings.py**

```
from settings_secret import *
```

and **.gitignore**

```
# Secret Settings
settings_secret.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try, `from .settings_secret import *` . [dot] ensures that you are importing from the current module.

Comment: Same error, this time saying ImportError: No module named 'gvlabs.settings_secret'

Comment: `os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET"  )`

Comment: I too think that getting secret key from the environment variable was the best practice.

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you. To clarify, I define `DJANGO_SECRET` in `settings_secret.py` and then in `settings.py` include the following: `SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get("DJANGO_SECRET")` ?

Comment: No you should set it as operating system's environment variable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14786072/keep-secret-keys-out-with-environment-variables . The link explains in detail.