# How/ what is wrong in my first view Django

Tags: django, view

please, tell me what is wrong in my first view Django because not working
https://github.com/Fgregorio1/ftgtraderexample.git

Comment: You haven't said what the problem is. 'not working' isn't enough information to help - please show the full error and traceback. You're less likely to get an answer if you link to a repository instead of showing the code here.

Comment: The repository consists of two django projects. One has the view that you want to access from the other's urls.py

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove second django project dir 'myproject'
2. Add 'path('', views.home, name='home'),' to your urls.py inside newsite

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from boards import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

additional i'd suggest:

- don't add venv directory to git repository (senseless)
- instead add '[requirements.txt](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files)' to project root with the needed packages
- Think about [making 'SECRET_KEY' really secret](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31884002/9857620)